# Flask-SocketIO handlers not working after being idle for some time

Tags: flask, websocket, celery, flask-socketio

I have a Flask REST API using Flask-SocketIO to keep the client updated on a background task running using Celery. Everything works properly for a while but after some time the Flask-SocketIO events stop being called.

No error appear in the logs, the messages from the client are received and so are the PING/PONG but the events stop being called. Restarting the Flask app fixes the issue temporarily, celery or redis don't need to be restarted and the tasks keep running. As if the Flask-SocketIO events are unregistered after a while.

I tried with and without monkey patch, I tried to register the events with socketio.on_event instead of the decorator. I also removed everything from the event except for a debug call but it's never called which suggests the emits are not the issue. The client is not the issue either, I tried with a barebone socket-IO client and get the same results. Moving the event to the 'connect' event doesn't work either, the client connects but the event is not called. Finally I also added a timeout between connecting a sending the get_count event but nothing there either.

The app is running with gunicorn. Behind nginx on a server but I get the same issue locally without nginx.

Here are the code snippets relevant to the issue.

extensions.py

```
from celery import Celery
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from logbook import debug

def init_celery(app, celery):
    """Add flask app context to celery.Task"""

    class ContextTask(celery.Task):
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery

celery = Celery("src", config_source="src.setup.celeryconfig")
socketio = SocketIO(cors_allowed_origins="*", logger=True, engineio_logger=True)
```

app.py

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()

from src.setup.extensions import (
    celery,
    init_celery,
    socketio
)

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config.from_object('src.'+os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])

    register_extensions(app)

    return app

def register_extensions(app):
    socketio.init_app(app, message_queue='redis://localhost:6379/0', )

@socketio.on_error()
def error_handler(e):
    debug("ERROR")
    debug(e)

@socketio.on('get_count')
def get_count(site_id):
    # This is not called after a while.
    debug('count')
    socketio.emit('count')


app = create_app()
celery = init_celery(app, celery=celery)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

Package versions:

```
celery==5.0.5
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-SocketIO==5.0.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
redis==3.5.3
```

Startup command

```
python gunicorn --worker-class 'eventlet' -w 1 -b :8004 -b :3443 --reload --timeout 1200 'src.app'
```

Logs when the problem occurs and with logger=True and socketio_logger=True:

```
deyiCxghwRYPLFXgAAAE: Sending packet OPEN data {'sid': 'deyiCxghwRYPLFXgAAAE', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingTimeout': 20000, 'pingInterval': 25000}
deyiCxghwRYPLFXgAAAE: Received packet MESSAGE data 0
deyiCxghwRYPLFXgAAAE: Sending packet MESSAGE data 0{"sid":"igeaCfCJlLAfvvSjAAAA"}
deyiCxghwRYPLFXgAAAE: Received request to upgrade to websocket
deyiCxghwRYPLFXgAAAE: Upgrade to websocket successful
deyiCxghwRYPLFXgAAAE: Received packet MESSAGE data 2["get_count","426"]
received event "get_count" from igeaCfCJlLAfvvSjAAAA [/]
deyiCxghwRYPLFXgAAAE: Received packet MESSAGE data 2["get_count","427"]
received event "get_count" from igeaCfCJlLAfvvSjAAAA [/]
deyiCxghwRYPLFXgAAAE: Received packet MESSAGE data 2["get_count","428"]
received event "get_count" from igeaCfCJlLAfvvSjAAAA [/]
deyiCxghwRYPLFXgAAAE: Sending packet PING data None
deyiCxghwRYPLFXgAAAE: Received packet PONG data
deyiCxghwRYPLFXgAAAE: Sending packet PING data None
deyiCxghwRYPLFXgAAAE: Received packet PONG data
deyiCxghwRYPLFXgAAAE: Sending packet PING data None
deyiCxghwRYPLFXgAAAE: Received packet PONG data
```

Logs after restarting the app, when everything works properly.

```
WBPV4M2jRjyx8HHmAAAA: Received packet MESSAGE data 0
WBPV4M2jRjyx8HHmAAAA: Sending packet MESSAGE data 0{"sid":"pv6lRFOFzmisdF0NAAAB"}
WBPV4M2jRjyx8HHmAAAA: Received request to upgrade to websocket
WBPV4M2jRjyx8HHmAAAA: Upgrade to websocket successful
WBPV4M2jRjyx8HHmAAAA: Received packet MESSAGE data 2["get_count","426"]
received event "get_count" from pv6lRFOFzmisdF0NAAAB [/]
WBPV4M2jRjyx8HHmAAAA: Received packet MESSAGE data 2["get_count","427"]
received event "get_count" from pv6lRFOFzmisdF0NAAAB [/]
WBPV4M2jRjyx8HHmAAAA: Received packet MESSAGE data 2["get_count","428"]
received event "get_count" from pv6lRFOFzmisdF0NAAAB [/]
emitting event "count" to all [/]
emitting event "count" to all [/]
emitting event "count" to all [/]
DEBUG: count
pubsub message: emit
WBPV4M2jRjyx8HHmAAAA: Sending packet MESSAGE data 2["count",{"room":"426","count":224,"total":224,"archive_exists":true}]
DEBUG: count
pubsub message: emit
WBPV4M2jRjyx8HHmAAAA: Sending packet MESSAGE data 2["count",{"room":"427","count":108,"total":108,"archive_exists":true}]
DEBUG: count
pubsub message: emit
WBPV4M2jRjyx8HHmAAAA: Sending packet MESSAGE data 2["count",{"room":"428","count":164,"total":165,"archive_exists":true}]
WBPV4M2jRjyx8HHmAAAA: Sending packet PING data None
WBPV4M2jRjyx8HHmAAAA: Received packet PONG data
WBPV4M2jRjyx8HHmAAAA: Sending packet PING data None
WBPV4M2jRjyx8HHmAAAA: Received packet PONG data
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: See the troubleshooting section of the docs to learn how to enable logging for Socket.IO. Then share logs for a server and a client during a time when the problem occurs.

Comment: I added the logs to my question. As you can see the event is received but there is no message sent back.

Comment: I'm not sure why the handler isn't invoked. Is it possible for you to create a small example application that reproduces the problem so that I can debug it?

Comment: I built the example app but after a few days it's still running properly. I'll be adding features until it fails, that should help identify the issue. https://github.com/AlekLefebvre/socket-io-minimal

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems resolved after updating my requirements to:

```
celery==5.1.0
Flask==1.1.4
Flask-SocketIO==5.1.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
redis==3.5.3
```